# Remove CSS & JS files from Wordpress Main Page For Increase Pagespeed?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, pagespeed

With the reference of [wordpress load plugin css/js in functions.php w/ conditional tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463304/wordpress-load-plugin-css-js-in-functions-php-w-conditional-tags) answered by @maiorano84

i am using **cforms**, **FancyBox**, **WP Page Numbers** plugins for **Wordpress**. From **Page Speed** point of view i want to remove CSS and JS of these plugin's from all pages except single post page. I also want to put the JS scripts in the footer. below is the code i have been trying but no luck. Would any body help me please?

```
if ( !is_single() ) {
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregisters', 100 );
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregisters', 100 );

    function my_deregisters() {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_page_numbers_stylesheet');
        wp_deregister_style( 'fancybox' ); 
        wp_deregister_script( 'fancybox' ); 
        wp_dequeue_script('fancybox');      
        wp_dequeue_style('fancybox'); 
        remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'mfbfw_load');
        remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'mfbfw_css');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'mfbfw_init');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'cforms_style');

        }

} else {  }
```

Comment: Can you confirm the function `my_deregisters` is being executed?

Comment: @levi this is the only code i am using even no **my_deregisters()**. it works without if condition and without **<?php my_deregisters(); ?>** any where. Should i execute it with <?php my_deregisters(); ?> in function.php ?

Comment: this question can possibly moved/asked @ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ram thanks for guidance. i have added it to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121264/remove-css-js-files-from-wordpress-main-page-for-increase-pagespeed

Comment: Check the Answer by @helgatheviking http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121264/remove-css-js-files-from-wordpress-main-page-for-increase-pagespeed